Jenkins CORS errors, Nginx Server and I have the CORS Plugin Installed
Good day everyone,
I have a very strange case that is repeating every 2 days now. I have a Digital Ocean Droplet that has Node js, Nginx & Jenkins Installed.
Now every 2 days, Jenkins simply block any api call giving me this error on the console:
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://backend.<MY_WEBSITE>.com/api/authenticate-admin' from origin 'https://admin.<MY_WEBSITE>.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

I've also checked nginx.config file with no location (Reverse proxy) settings, the config is basically the default settings for Nginx.
What Could be done to prevent such a Problem!
I have the CORS Plugin installed already @ Jenkins, But Still every 2 days this would happen.
As a workaround I'd have to re-build my project, the problem then disappears... this it happens again!
